# php mysql query, insert works ok, delete not working

Tags: php, mysql

```
$updatesql = "UPDATE users SET firstname = '$newfirstname', surname='$newsurname', email ='$newemail', password ='$newpassword' WHERE user_id = '$userid'";
mysql_query($updatesql);
```

The above insert query works just fine, the delete below doesn't, no errors returned. ????
Code on same page, activated by different submit buttons, have tested these with echo's, and all is good there.

```
$deletesql= "DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id = '$userid'";
mysql_query($deletesql);
```

Comment: please stop using mysql_query..It has been deprecated

Comment: Did you check the $userid value on debug?

Comment: if the query is fine it should work fine!

Comment: the query is fine. Try to check if $userId has any value or not

Answer (score 0):

u can try this way

```
$deletesql= "DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id = '".$userid."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

first way is this : replace '$userid' with a number and test that

if worked change  '$userid' to '".$recordid."'

if not work you must see errors :

```
$deletesql= 'DELETE FROM users 
        WHERE user_id =1';

mysql_select_db('yourdb');
$retval = mysql_query( $deletesql, $yourconnection);
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not delete data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Deleted data successfully\n";
mysql_close($yourconnection);
```

Comment: Returns, 'Could not delete data:'

Comment: Correction, returns this; Could not delete data: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`shop`.`orders`, CONSTRAINT `orders_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`))

Answer (score 0):

may your foreign key constrains fail. check whether any foreign key check fails.
That is, check whether any other tables has any relationship with this table.